# How to center ScrollView that is in StackView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I can't center pushed ScrollView into the StackView. I've tried a bunch of ways, but nothing works. Can you help me with this, please?

```
//Main.qml
...
StackView {
    id: stackView
    anchors.fill: parent
    initialItem: mainView
}
Loader {
    id: serialportLoader
    active: false
    source: "secondFile.qml"
}
...
//Push "secondFile.qml" by pressing a button with the action:
Action {
    id: openSerialportSettings
    text: "Open serial port"
    onTriggered: {
        serialportLoader.active = true;
        stackView.push(serialportLoader.item);
    }
}
...
```

```
//secondFile.qml
ScrollView   {
    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 5
//        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            height: 50
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
...
```

[image: How it looks]
If I add an empty Item to the ScrollView, it comes to the center but no longer scrollable:

```
ScrollView   {
    Item {
    }
    ColumnLayout {
...
```

[image]

I guess I'm just using ScrollView wrong, because I get these results with ScrollView and Page instead of it:

```
ScrollView/*Page*/  {
    id: topItem
    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 5
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            height: 200
            width: 300
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In [Online editor](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: In the code that you're showing, the ScrollView gets added to a Loader, not a StackView. Is there something missing?

Comment: @JarMan sorry, I push it with the Action (updated description)

Comment: I guess I'm just using ScrollView wrong because I get nice results with Page instead of ScrollView (but not scrollable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by JarMan, the cause of the problem/confusion is your implementation of Loader makes your StackView implementation ambiguous. I have created a version of your application just using the StackView and made that receive "SecondPage.qml":

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    header: AppToolBar { }
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "MainView.qml"
    }
}

// MainView.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Label {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "MainView.qml"
    }
    Button {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: parent.height * 3 / 4
        text: "Go To Second Page"
        onClicked: stackView.push("SecondPage.qml")
    }
}

// SecondPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Label {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "SecondPage.qml"
    }
    Button {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: parent.height * 3 / 4
        text: "Back"
        onClicked: stackView.pop()
    }
}

// AppToolBar.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
ToolBar {
    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        ToolButton {
            enabled: stackView.depth > 1
            icon.source: "chevron-left-32.svg"
            opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
        Label {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "Page Title"
            horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }
        ToolButton {
            icon.source: "handle-vertical-32.svg"
        }
    }
}

// chevron-left-32.svg: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/chevron-left-32.svg

// handle-vertical-32.svg: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/calcite-ui-icons/master/icons/handle-vertical-32.svg
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you, got some useful stuff from your code! But I'd like not to delete "SecondPage.qml" object after popping it, that's why I used Loader.

I guess I'm just using ScrollView wrong because I get nice results with Page instead of ScrollView (but not scrollable).

I tried it with your online editor and get the same results - added a link to my question

Comment: That's easy. To keep pages persistent, you just declare them inline, e.g. `Page { id: secondPage; visible: false }` then you just `stackView.push(secondPage)`. The page just appears and disappears and is never destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, I think now I can deal with it :)